# How can i center the div background color in another tag

Tags: html, css

sorry for the inconvenience, does anyone know how I could do to center the nav inside the header (using the background-color) using the css?

the code i've writed so far:

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body>header {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
}

header>nav {
  background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav></nav>
</header>
<section>
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>
  <footer></footer>
</section>
<section>
  <header></header>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <footer></footer>
  </article>
  <article>
    <header></header>
    <p></p>
    <aside></aside>
    <footer></footer>
  </article>
  <footer></footer>
</section>
<footer></footer>
```

how is the page now:

[image]

I want the lighter part to be centered on the darker color
any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to vertically align elements in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/how-to-vertically-align-elements-in-a-div)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `display: flex`

```css
header {
  background-color: gray;
  height: 100px;
  /* add below styles */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

header>nav {
  background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav></nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Esercizio 2</title>
    <style>
        body{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body>header{
            background-color: gray;
            height: 100px;

            /* add below styles */
            display: grid;
            align-content: center;
        }
        header>nav{
            background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
            height: 50px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            /* remove margin-top: 15px */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav></nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <header></header>
        <nav></nav>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header></header>
        <article>
            <header></header>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <footer></footer>
        </article>
        <article>
            <header></header>
            <p></p>
            <aside></aside>
            <footer></footer>
        </article>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <footer></footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps

```html
<html lang="en"><head><meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Esercizio 2</title>

    <style>
        body{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 600px;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        body>header{
            background-color: gray;
            height: 100px;
        }
        header>nav{
            background-color: rgb(156, 156, 156);
            height: 50px;
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: 20px;
            margin-top: 15px;
            transform: translate(0%, 50%);
            -ms-transform: translate(0%, 50%);
        }
    </style></head><body>


    <header>
        <nav></nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <header></header>
        <nav></nav>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <section>
        <header></header>
        <article>
            <header></header>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
            <footer></footer>
        </article>
        <article>
            <header></header>
            <p></p>
            <aside></aside>
            <footer></footer>
        </article>
        <footer></footer>
    </section>
    <footer></footer></body></html>
```